# Nesting up scss with main.scss and subcomponent scss files

Tags: css, sass

I have one global **main.scss** file where i have declared one

```
.small-size-text{
font-size: 12px;
}
```

And in subcomponent file as **login.scss** i have defined one other class as

```
@import 'main.scss';

.title-content{
    color: red
    }
```

Now I have to use same property in as single className.

```
<p className='title-content'> Hello World</p>
```

Which contains both property?

like `.title-content{font-size: 12px; color: red}`

Answer (score 2):

you need to extend you second class with the first import work ith cascading so you can do this :

main scss

```
 .small-size-text{
    font-size: 12px;
    }
```

login.scss

```
@import 'main.scss';

.title-content{
    @extend .small-size-text;
    color: red;
}
```